# Mallocing structs in C

Tags: c, memory, struct

When I allocate memory for a struct like this:

```
typedef struct _My_struct {
    int myInt;
} My_struct;

My_struct* tmp = (My_struct*)malloc(sizeof(My_struct));
```

And I then try to set some values in it like so:

```
tmp->myInt = 0;
```

my program crashes.
When running in debug mode, I see that all of the values in tmp are NULL, so it probably crashes because of a NullPointerException.
Why can't I allocate memory properly?

Comment: I just ran your code using this test: `#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _My_struct {
    int myInt;
} My_struct;

int main(void)
{
    My_struct* tmp = malloc(sizeof(My_struct));
    tmp->myInt = 1424838;
    printf("%d\n", tmp->myInt);
    return 0;
}` . Looks OK, no compiler warnings, runs OK. So the error must be elsewhere in your code. BTW, don't cast the `malloc()` result in C.

Comment: There is no need to type cast the resulting malloc call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working. You can even [test it online](http://ideone.com/njhilY). You must have some mistake or error that you didn't show us.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    typedef struct _My_struct {
        int myInt;
    } My_struct;

    My_struct* tmp = malloc(sizeof(My_struct));

    tmp->myInt = 5;
    printf("Output: %d", tmp->myInt);

}
```

**Output**

```
Output: 5
```

Answer (score 2):

My mistake. Forgot the `#include <stdlib.h>`. My compiler didn't seem to care though, weird. 
Thanks anyways!

Comment: I have a feeling that the compiler complained bitterly, but you just ignored the warnings. If there weren't any warnings, then you need to turn up the warning level `-Wall` with gcc or clang, `/W4` with microsoft. And as always, fix all warnings or you're a [turnip](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fall_off_the_turnip_truck).

Comment: This is why you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`. If you left that out you would have gotten a compiler warning.

Comment: Right. I will do that in the future. Thanks.